# Azure DevOps Access Custom Field From Script

Tags: variables, azure-devops

I have a required custom field on any ticket created (Bug, Tasks, PBI).

I have a pipeline that creates tickets automatically, but the values that are used to create these tickets doesn't have a value for my custom field. I want to set this custom field by adding an entry to the pipeline variables, but I don't know the variable name of the custom field.

How can I find the variable name of the custom field so I can access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to determine your custom variable name.

ADO has a bunch of APIs.  The following will give you all the details of a specific work type. For my case I needed the "bug" work type.

```
/* 
    Api to display work type fields in JSON format
    Replace {} with correct values
*/

https://dev.azure.com/{orginization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}/fields?api-version=6.0
```

The resulting JSON will give you a whole list of variables. Here is what the System Variable and a Custom Variable look like.

[image]

The `referenceName` is the variable name you would use in your scripts, etc.

**TL;DR** -
Take your field name and remove all spacing and then put `Custom.` in front of it.

`Custom.FieldNameWithNoSpace`